# Drag and drop table view controller into view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I am using Xcode 5 and iOS SDK 7.1 and am following a tutorial that says you should drag and drop a table view controller into a view controller as shown below.

[image: Adding Table View Controller]

However when I drag and drop into the view controller, it doesn't accept the table view controller and the icon (table view controller) just moves back to its original position in the object library. I've tried zooming in to the fullest but this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: There is a difference between a tableView and a tableViewController, are you sure you're using the correct one?

Comment: @Logan Thanks a lot. That was the problem. Can't believe it was so trivial

Comment: you can drag and drop a view controller into another view controller. try to drag and drop uitableview instead of tableViewController

Comment: @Fourth - I thought that might be it, it's easy to miss little stuff when you're starting out because you haven't made the mistake yet.  I submitted as an answer if you'd like to close this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the problem you're having is that you're trying to drag a `UITableViewController` when the tutorial wants you to drag a `UITableView`.  There is a difference.